# В зависимости от введенного числа, программа должна корректно подставлять окончание для слов python

Tags: python

```
n = int(input('enter n: '))  
if n%10== 1:  
    print(n,"компьютер")  
elif (n%10==2 or n%10==3 or n%10==4):  
    print(n,"компьютера")  
else:  
    print(n,'компьютеров')
```

при n=12/13/14 должно быть компьютеров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение вашей проблемы очень простое, вам всего лишь нужно добавить одно условие (дам вам лучшее решение, при условии что версия Python >= 3.7):

```
n = int(input())
if n in (11, 12, 13, 14):
    print(f'{n} компьютеров')
elif n % 10 == 1:
    print(f'{n} компьютер')
elif n % 10 in (2, 3, 4):
    print(f'{n} компьютера')
else:
    print(f'{n} компьютеров')
```

Answer (score 0):

ну так словами запишите алгоритм

3 формы - 1) компьютер 2) компьютера 3) компьютеров

1. если последние 2 цифры в диапазоне от 10 до 19 - 3 форма
2. если последняя цифра от 5 до 9 или 0 - 3 форма
3. если последняя цифра от 2 до 4 - 2 форма
4. если последняя цифра 1 - 1 форма

т.е.

```
if n % 100 >= 10 and n % 100 < 20 or n % 10 > 4 or n % 10 == 0:
    print('ов')
elif n % 10 == 1:
    print('')
else:
    print('a')
```

можно покомпактнее

```
if (n % 100) % 10 == 1 or n % 10 > 4 or n % 10 == 0:
    print('ов')
elif n % 10 == 1:
    print('')
else:
    print('a')
```